# Flutter it says The return type 'int' isn't a 'Null'

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I encountered this error. It says "The return type 'int' isn't a 'Null', as required by the closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure"

I tried troubleshooting however I can't get to fix the error

`

```
`class _SelectButton extends StatelessWidget {
  int _value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpCubit, SignUpState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.email != current.email,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => setState(() => _value = 0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 56,
                  width: 56,
                  color: _value == 0 ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
                  child: Icon(Icons.call),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 4),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => setState(() => _value = 1),
                child: Container(
                  height: 56,
                  width: 56,
                  color: _value == 1 ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
                  child: Icon(Icons.message),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void setState(Null Function() param0) {}
}
```

`

Comment: Why do you have a `setState` method into a `StatelessWidget`? The whole point of a `StatelessWidget` is to don't have a state. It might be the problem. Try to use a `StatefulWidget` instead.

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick answer. 
I made it StatefulWidget and got this error in  onTap: () => setState(() => _value = 0),
"setState(()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you auto generated setState which is implemented in `StatefulWidget`
please delete your `setState`  method and change your `StatelessWidget` with `StatefulWidget`
you can change it easy by using alt+enter from your IDE to change it

Comment: Hello @mohamed
This is how my code looks like 

class _RadioButton extends StatefulWidget {
  }

Have this at the bottom
  setState(int Function() param0) {}
}

Now I'm getting this error in _radioButton class
Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'.
Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.

What do you think will be the best solution?

Comment: StatefulWidget  must has **@override** for  createState()
please review this docs.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: don't forget to mark solve to my answer

Comment: That's clicking the check icon right?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class _RadioButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioButtonState createState() => _RadioButtonState();
}

class _RadioButtonState extends State<_RadioButton> {
  String _value = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpCubit, SignUpState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.email != current.email,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => setState(() => _value = "Coach"),
                child: Container(
                  height: 56,
                  width: 56,
                  color: _value == "Coach" ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.call),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 4),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => setState(() => _value = "Player"),
                child: Container(
                  height: 56,
                  width: 56,
                  color: _value == "Player" ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.message),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).